# How to recursively list all files of desired file type in a specified directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want list all `.java` files in the desired directory using `.bat` script in Windows. When I run this:

```
set JMETALHOME=%cd%
dir %JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems /S /B
```

it lists all the files in the `problems` directory. But when I want to filter the files only to the java files:

```
set JMETALHOME=%cd%
dir %JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems /S /B *.java > sources.txt
```

it lists all the `.java` files in the `%JMETALHOME%` folder.

Comment: `dir %JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems\*.java /S /B > sources.txt`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks post it as a answer to upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common methods to get names of all files with a specific file extension found in a directory tree recursively with full path. One common method is using command **DIR** and the other common method is using command **FOR**.

Example code demonstrating both methods for *.java and *.html files:

```
@echo off
set "JMETALHOME=%CD%"

dir "%JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems\*.java" "%JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems\*.html" /B /S >SourcesDir.txt

if exist SourcesFor1.txt del SourcesFor1.txt
for /R "%JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems" %%I in (*.java *.html) do echo %%I>>SourcesFor1.txt

(for /R "%JMETALHOME%\jmetal\problems" %%I in (*.java *.html) do echo %%I)>SourcesFor2.txt
```

**DIR** requires the specification of 1 or even more wildcard patterns together with path (absolute or relative).

**FOR** offers the possibility to specify the path separately from the wildcard patterns.

**FOR** outputs the found file names line by line which requires either usage of `>>` redirection operator with an extra deletion of a perhaps already existing output file before running **FOR** as demonstrated above with `SourcesFor1.txt` example, or embedding **FOR** itself in a block and use `>` to redirect everything output by the block into a file overwriting a perhaps already existing file as demonstrated with `SourcesFor2.txt` example.

On second **FOR** example make sure not having a space between `echo %%I` and closing parenthesis `)` of the block because otherwise this space would be appended on each file name written into output file `SourcesFor2.txt`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).